# How to use a dynamically resizing String Array?

Tags: c++, arrays, string, dynamic

I'm trying to use an array in C++ that changes in size. For some reason the size does not change, it only ever holds 1 string. The difficult part is that the user cannot input the number of courses they are going to add, instead the `addCourse` function is called until the user stops. A vector cannot be used (this is for a school assignment, and a resizing array is required). I'm stuck as to why the array only seems to hold one string, I would think it to hold the equivalent of `numCourses` strings. How would I go about resizing to hold multiple strings after each call to the function?

```
void Student::addCourse(string* courseName)
{
    int x;
    numCourses += 1;//increments number of courses

    string newCourse = *courseName;

    string* newCourses = new string[numCourses];//temporary array

    for(x=0; x<numCourses - 1; x++)//fills temp array with the values of the old
    {
        newCourses[x] = courses[x];
    }

    newCourses[numCourses - 1] = newCourse;//adds extra value

    delete[] courses;//removes original array

    courses = newCourses;//sets the new course list
}
```

Edit: For those asking why a vector cannot be used because the point of the assignment is to actively avoid memory leak using the heap. Using an array like this forces intentional delete of stored values.

Comment: You are doing things **in a C way**, like passing pointers as parameters for pass by reference, and creating and deallocating dynamic arrays through `new`/`delete` operators. You should learn more about C++, and its way to do things. Specifically, this could be achieved easily with a `std::vector<std::string>`

Comment: `std::vector<std::string>`...

Comment: @H2CO3 "A vector cannot be used (this is for a school assignment [...]"

Comment: do you have all array filled with the same course?

Comment: I would put forward to your teacher that a vector or list would be better suited for this task. My experience tells me that teachers aren't always right and arbitrary tasks like this won't prepare you for the real world.

Comment: Also don't declare variables at the beginning of a block. That hasn't been necessary for many years. Just use for(int x=0; x<numCourses...

Comment: @BartoszKP I'm sorry.

Comment: *"A vector cannot be used (this is for a school assignment [...]"* You should go to suggest your teacher to learn C++. That exercise and style is the way to learn C, not the way to learn good C++

Comment: There is nothing (functionally) wrong with the code you've presented: http://ideone.com/khAjuD. Why do you think that it doesn't resize the array?

Comment: How do you know you there is only one string in the array? Let me rephrase: How do you think you know it? :)

Comment: @Manu343726 I don't find knowing the principle of how the `std::vector` works a way to learn only C. Your judgement about the teacher you know almost nothing about seems a bit hasty.

Comment: @BartoszKP the problem with that style is that people never understand the good modern C++ style, and keeps them in a poorly pseudo-C style.

Comment: @BartoszKP first learn to use the tool, later learn how the tool is implemented

Comment: @Manu343726 Well, yes, this is a good point.

Comment: @BartoszKP one of the reasons because there are a lot of bad "C++ programmers" is that people still keep teaching C++ as if it was C. C++ should be teached as if it was C++. I'm pretty sure that no one python tutorial starts with pointers, stack vs heap, and how python tuples are implemented. It starts with the natural and user-friendly syntax of python. That should be the same for C++ teaching/learning.

Comment: Note for the downvoter: Even if this is not the best example of C++ programming, there is no reason to post a downvote at all. OP is learning C++, and he has no blame about the style of his code. He is only posting a question, even if its content is far away of good C++ practices

Comment: I am using vs 2012 and I know the array only holds one value because I walkthrough with the debugger. The array immediately after being created with numCourses >= 2 only holds one value. Also, I have a returnCourses function which will only return the first value, then blank spaces for the rest because the function is called numCourses times.

Comment: Visual Studio shows only one element in the debugger for dynamic arrays (the debugger has no direct way to determine how much elements are in that array). And for Visual Studio this isn't even an array but in the first case only a pointer to a string.

Comment: Also if you use an `std::vector` the VS debugger understands it and shows you the content (All elements) of the vector.

Comment: @simon fisher also note that the return function, which grabs the values only returns the first, then blank values. The returnCourses looks like: string returnClass(int index){string class = courses(index); return class;} this returns a blank string for any index>0

Comment: The problem seems to be on another place, your function works (i tested it).

Answer (score 1):

The comment should have answered your question: there is no way for the debugger to know that a pointer to a string is pointed to an array, nor does it know its bounds, because no such information is kept at runtime (a std::vector will show its whole contents in the debugger, in contrast).

Answer (score 0):

Your method prototype should read:

```
void Student::addCourse(const string& courseName);
```

If you don't want to have a memory leak, declare a pointer to courses in your class:

```
private:
    string* courses;
```

Allocate space for an array of strings in your constructor:

```
Student::Student() 
{
    courses = new String[5];
}
```

Then deallocate in the destructor:
    Student::~Student()
    {
        delete[] courses;
    }

This gives you room for up to 5 courses.  If you need more you need to adjust the size of the array of strings at run time:

```
void Student::ExtendArray()
{
    delete[] courses;
    courses = new String[10];
}
```

Note this code is not exception safe, but will give you the basic idea.

Comment: You can delete your own comments by clicking on the "x" symbol that appears at the end of your comment when you hover over your comment.